# How to assign objects to a Point array using a for each loop

Tags: java, arrays, object

Edit: yes I know how to do it with a for loop

I do this

```
    Point [] pointArray = new Point [10];

    for(Point p : pointArray)
        p = new Point(1,2);
```

But this line prints `null`

```
    System.out.println(pointArray[0]); //Prints null
```

Although it's okay to do this

```
    pointArray[0] = new Point(1,2);
    System.out.println(pointArray[0]); //Prints java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `p` in `for(Pointer p : pointArray)` is a reference to the objects referenced in the array. The objects referenced in the array are null. I am just referencing `p` when I assign a new object to it.

Answer (score 1):

In your enhanced for loop p is not an alias for the array element. It only has the value for the element it doesn't reference the object in the array

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over nulls and you are assigning the new Point object to the reference but you are not actually storing it to the array, hence you are not able to see the records.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the enhanced for loop to modify or write data in the array through the iterator, only read it it.

The regular for loop however can modify data...

```
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
          array[i] = point(1,2)
   }
```

...

@Arachnid Hivemind

As Arachnid Hivemind stated in his answer...

"In your enhanced for loop p is not an alias for the array element. It only has the value for the element it doesn't reference the object in the array"

Comment: Huh, no shit. Didn't know. Any idea why?

Comment: Arachnid havemind explains well...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the difference b/w them

**foreach vs. for: Basic differences**

The only practical difference between `for` and `foreach` is that, in the case of indexable objects, you do not have access to the index. An example when the basic for loop is required:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  {
   if(i < 10)  {
      //Do some work
   }  else  {
      //Do other stuff
   }
}
```

Although you could manually create a separate index int-variable with foreach

```
int idx = -1;
for(int i : intArray)  {
   idx++;
   ...
}
```

it is not recommended, since variable-scope is not ideal, and the basic for loop is simply the standard and expected format for this use-case.

**Foreact loop can not be used if**

Needs access to the `iterator` in order to remove the current element. The **for-each loop hides the iterator**, so you cannot call **remove/add**. Therefore, the for-each loop is not usable for filtering. Similarly it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, use an index with the array if you wish to assign values to the elements in the array.

However you might like to consider using java 8 streams to create and initialise your array rather than splitting this into two operations. I find this to be a fairly convenient way to set up arrays of this type.

For example:

```
Point[] points = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(n -> new Point(n, 2)).toArray();
```

This avoids the problem of having to iterate through the array using indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Point p : pointArray)
    // rest of the code goes here
```

The above statement is the same as

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++)
    Point p = pointArray[i];
    // rest of the code goes here
```

There is no point in using a forearch loop to fill an array as it is not its purpose. Here is one way to do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++)
    pointArray[i] = new Point(0,0);
```

Now that your array "pointArray" is initialized, you can use a foreach loop to access its elements.